# Batch To Bash Conversion

Tags: bash, batch-file

I need to know this Batch Script into Bash :

```
@echo off
set /p name= Name? 
findstr /m "%name%" ndatabase.txt
if %errorlevel%==0 (
cls
echo The name is found in the database!
pause >nul
exit
)
cls
echo.
echo Name not found in database.
pause >nul
exit
```

I am new to the Linux Kernel, so starting off with an easy distro - Ubuntu 12.10. My problem is that I do not really know much of Bash Script, since I am very accustomed to the Batch Script format; which is obviously a bad habit for my C++.

Comment: Bash has nothing to do with the Linux kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Name? " name

clear

if [ $(grep -qF "$name" ndatabase.txt) ]
then
    read -p "The name is found in the database!" PAUSE

else
    read -p "Name not found in database." PAUSE
fi
```

and a shorter version:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Name? " name
[ $(grep -qF "$name" ndatabase.txt) ] && echo "The name is found in the database!" || echo "Name not found in database."
```

Comment: +1. I would use `read -p "Name? " name` and `if grep -qF "$name" file; then ...` -- you might add the equivalent of "pause": `read -p "Hit Enter to continue" x`

Answer (score 0):

Umm "Korn shell" is very closely related to Bash (see oreilly 'Learning the Korn Shell' by Rosenblatt')

```
@echo off             ::: has no linux/bash meaning  
set /p name= Name?    ::: read input from prompt 'name?' --- _'echo -n "name?"; read TERM;'_  
findstr /m "%name%" ndatabase.txt ::: _grep $TERM ndatabase.txt_   

if %errorlevel%==0  ::: _if (($! == 0 )); then_   enclosed with _fi_; the (( means numeric   
cls                 ::: no real linux/bash meaning (maybe multiple _echo_ statements  
pause               ::: can be faked with _read_  
_exit_ translates rather well.        
_$$_=process id (aka pid) _$@_ commandline arguments, there are others : _$!_ is last exit code
var=_$(command)_     var (with **NO** dollarsign assumes the contents of _command_'s output
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is as direct as possible:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Name? " name
fgrep -le "$name" ndatabase.txt 
if [ $? = 0 ]; then
    clear
    echo "The name is found in the database!"
    read -n1 >/dev/null
    exit
fi
clear
echo
echo "Name not found in database."
read -n1 >/dev/null
exit
```

As others have mentioned there are shorter, more elegant solutions though.